# Adding parameter to AuthorizeAttribute constructor causes failure in MvcSiteMapProvider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I've been using MvcSiteMapProvider based on authorize attributes and it was all right until we introduced a new class derived from `AuthorizeAttribute`. Main difference is in its constructor signature:

```
public MyAuthorizeAttribute(param RoleCode[] roles) {
    Roles = string.join(",", roles.Select(r => r.ToString());
}
```

And... MvcSiteMapProvider shown unexpected result: only actions marked by `MyAuthorizeAttribute` became invisible. I've checked that by disabling this constructor - everything went as it had been before adding a parameter to the constructor. Also - it's not `params` specific - any parameter (event int) leads to such behaviour.

AS I understood from MvcSiteMapProvider sources, it emits some code to emulate authorize attributes - but looks like it's impossible to save assembly generated by external code. I know that there is a workaround - use some kind of enumerable property, but have you got any suggestions how to make it work with constructor parameters? Do you know why MvcSiteMapProvider behaves like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after spending some time in debugging, I realized the answer: **dynamic proxies**.

The problem is that during request execution inside MVC framework there is no easy way to find out how a class derived from `AuthorizeAttribute` performs its work. In case of access check failure some could throw exception, some - return 401 status code, some redirect to login page at once, and so on.

But MvcSiteMapProvides does that! It uses the following workaround:

- if class is `AuthorizeAttribute`:

  - create an instance of `InternalAuthorize` class which is fairly simple.
  - copy all properties there and
  - invoke `AuthorizeCore` method which returns boolean value.
- else

  - generate a proxy class derived from a type of attribute,
  - create instance, */// << here we get an exception*
  - copy all properties there and
  - invoke `AuthorizeCore` method which returns boolean value.

As it is clear, that's not an easy task to make a proxy, which is aware of your constructor parameters. Exception about default constructor absence is thrown, of course, but it is then consumed by empty catch clause. That is really sad - at least a single debug trace would have saved me a couple of hours.

So the answer at last:

- Obviously you should use parameterless attribute constructor (why oh why that's not mentioned anywhere?)
- Make custom acl provider: implement `IAclModule` interface and unleash your knowledge about your own authorize attributes within it.